# Passing data as state in history.pushState in angular

Tags: angular, location, history, pushstate

I know you can do it with the help of services, that is passing data between two controllers/ts files. But what i wanna do is say i have a page A, page B and then page C, i open a new tab, go to page A, then to page B, and to page C. On c page i have onPopState and have replaced C with B page, now, I want to pass the data PAGEC from pageC to pageB in history.pushState('pageC',null,pageBURL)

if this is right, how do i read the pageC state in pageB? window.PopStateEvent doesnt give anything.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes sir, i am trying to find a state data in pageB, tried looking at every window object data on page B but i couldnt

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code that you have tried?